# How to use AMP components in Angular Elements app

Tags: angular, amp-html, shadow-dom, angular-elements

I'm trying to use set of amp components in angular app. Everything works with standard view encapsulation, but my application needs to be built as angular element with shadow dom view encapsulation, in which case amp components are not rendering.
As I understand there is a way to include whole amp document by url with shadow-v0.js, but I need just one component, and I also didn't manage to find any working example of amp.attachShadowDoc.
If I'm including shadow-v0.js script it seems like it's trying to do something with amp component template, but failing with error:

```
No ampdoc found for [object HTMLElement]
```

Is there a way to include amp component in angular app with shadow dom view encapsulation?